# Transparency showing up as black when blending with other transparent objects in cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency

I'm working on a wormhole, and to achieve a pseudo-volumetric look, I have multiple stacked objects using transparency. All textures are procedural. I'm getting black artifacts when rendering in cycles, specifically where transparent parts visually overlap. How can I fix this?

[image: wormhole]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at cycles light path settings
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/light_paths.html
Increase the transparency and total bounces

Comment: Yay!.............

Answer (score 1):

In the material(s) properties Viewport Display settings, change the Blend Mode.

[image]