# Multiple image planes shadows being funky

Tags: hair

So, I have a feather/hair particle system, which is using image plains as object for the particles, but when I render in cycles it does some weird stuff with the shadows

[image: This is what it looks like]

I have no idea how to fix this at all

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

See these:

[Transparency showing up as black when blending with other transparent objects in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249471/transparency-showing-up-as-black-when-blending-with-other-transparent-objects-in)

[Transparent image planes near each other are black](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99647/transparent-image-planes-near-each-other-are-black)

**Basically, you need to increase your transparent samples in the render settings column.**[image]

Comment: Thanks, this helped some but, is there a way to do it without multiplying my render times by infinite?

Comment: If you can, use eevee, and use 'alpha clipped' shadows and transparency in the material on the planes. Otherwise, try a number like 20 or so to see if it works.